# How is the access token generated from a managed identity in Azure used with the Python SDK?

Tags: python, azure, token, azure-keyvault, azure-sdk

I've setup a VM machine in Azure that has a managed identity.
I follow the guide here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-linux-vm-access-arm

So now I have an access token. But what I fail to understand is how do I use this token to access my key vault? I'm using the Python SDK. Looking at the docs for the SDK here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-keyvault/azure.keyvault?view=azure-python

There exist a access token class `AccessToken(scheme, token, key)`
I assume i can use my token i generated earlier here. But what is scheme and key? The docs does not explain it. Or am I looking at the wrong class to use with the token?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a VM with a managed identity, then you can create a credential for a Key Vault client using [azure-identity](https://pypi.org/project/azure-identity/)'s [`ManagedIdentityCredential` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.managedidentitycredential?view=azure-python). The credential will fetch and use access tokens for you as you use the Key Vault client:

```
from azure.identity import ManagedIdentityCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient

credential = ManagedIdentityCredential()
client = SecretClient("https://{vault-name}.vault.azure.net", credential)
secret = client.get_secret("secret-name")
```

Note that I'm using a [`SecretClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/python/api/azure-keyvault-secrets/azure.keyvault.secrets.secretclient?view=azure-python) to fetch secrets from Key Vault; there are new packages for working with Key Vault in Python that replace `azure-keyvault`:

- [azure-keyvault-certificates](https://pypi.org/project/azure-keyvault-certificates/) [(Migration guide)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-certificates/migration_guide.md)
- [azure-keyvault-keys](https://pypi.org/project/azure-keyvault-keys/) [(Migration guide)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-keys/migration_guide.md)
- [azure-keyvault-secrets](https://pypi.org/project/azure-keyvault-secrets/) [(Migration guide)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-secrets/migration_guide.md)

Clients in each of these packages can use any credential from [azure-identity](https://pypi.org/project/azure-identity/) for authentication.

(I work on the Azure SDK in Python)

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't recommend you use the managed identity of a VM to access KeyVault.  You should create a service principal if you intend on running scripts / code.

The best way of doing this is with the Azure CLI.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli) for instructions on installing the CLI, and refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/python/python-sdk-azure-authenticate?view=azure-python), or [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-create-for-rbac) for creating your service principal.

The best way to manage resources in Python is by using ADAL, which is documented:

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python

In your case, however, managing KeyVault is made a little easier since the KeyVault library for Python also provides the means for you to authenticate without directly using ADAL to obtain your access token.  See here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/key-vault?view=azure-python

```
from azure.keyvault import KeyVaultClient
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id = '...',
    secret = '...',
    tenant = '...'
)

client = KeyVaultClient(credentials)

# VAULT_URL must be in the format 'https://<vaultname>.vault.azure.net'
# KEY_VERSION is required, and can be obtained with the KeyVaultClient.get_key_versions(self, vault_url, key_name) API
key_bundle = client.get_key(VAULT_URL, KEY_NAME, KEY_VERSION)
key = key_bundle.key
```

In the above, client_id, secret, and tenant (id) are all outputs of the `az ad sp create-for-rbac --name {APP-NAME}` CLI command.

Remember to review and adjust the role assignments for the sp you created.  And your KeyVault is only as secure as the devices which have access to your sp's credentials.